# Advanced Find compare columns

Tags: dynamics-365

I need to get a list from the child entity to the case and run a workflow where the owner of the child is not equal to parent(case). I don't see the option in advanced find to compare columns in the parent and child
Something like current (owner) does not equal to Related parent( owner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. It is only possible to compare columns that reside in the same the table/record.

See [MS Docs - Use column comparison in queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/column-comparison#limitations).